# How do I create a regex expression for a 10 digit phone number with the same separator?

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a basic regular expression to match a phone number which can either use dots [.] or hyphens [-] as the separator.
The format is 123.456.7890 or 123-456-7890.
The expression I am currently using is:

```
\d\d\d[-.]\d\d\d[-.]\d\d\d\d
```

The issue here is that it also matches the phone numbers that have both separators in them which I want to be termed as invalid/not a match. For example, with my expression, 123.456-7890 and 123-456.7890 show up as a match, something I do not want happening.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a backreference:

```regex
^\d{3}([.-])\d{3}\1\d{4}$
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
^       from the start of the number
\d{3}   match any 3 digits
([.-])  then match AND capture either a dot or a dash separator
\d{3}   match any 3 digits
\1      match the SAME separator seen earlier
\d{4}   match any 4 digits
$       end of the number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d{3}([-.])\d{3}\1\d{4}$
```

You can see that it works [here](https://regex101.com/r/numV4j/1).

Key point here - is that you capture your desired character using brackets `([-.])`

and then reuse it with back reference `\1`.